# How to authenticate into a Redis stream from spark with an ssl certificate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ssl, redis, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to access a Redis server that needs an ssl certificate to authenticate through spark with Scala. I understand SparkSession has a parameter "spark.redis.ssl" which takes in a boolean value of 'true' or 'false'. However I would like to know where exactly to I key in the path to my stored ssl certificate if the set the "spark.redis.ssl" option to 'true'.

```
    val spark = SparkSession
        .builder
        .master("local[*]")
        .config("spark.redis.host", "dummy.redis.server.ip")
        .config("spark.redis.port", "1234")
        .config("spark.redis.user", "redis_dude")
        .config("spark.redis.auth", "abc@123")
        .config("spark.redis.ssl", true)
        .getOrCreate()
```

This is how I establish my spark session. How do I go about form there. Where do I key in the path to my ssl/tls certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Your spark application is a client for Redis server and it doesn't need a TLS certificate. The certificate is stored on Redis server only.

Comment: However, when I connect to the redis server using redis-cli in shell or when using redisinsight to connect to redis, we are asked to key in the path to the ssl certificate or copy/paste the entire certificate in order to connect. Why isn't the same happening with spark. You know that **redis-cli** has a '--tls --cert' parameter right .....